# Ajax - Can't get json data 

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm quite a beginner in ajax technology. I have a php for execute a mysql_query and I would like to use the result on the client side.

My `database.php`:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM customers");
$res=mysql_fetch_array($q);
echo json_encode($res);
```

and my `client.php`

```
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced </div>

<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function () 
{
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'database.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
  data: "",                        

  dataType: 'json',                //data format      
  success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
  {
    var name = data[0];              

     $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+name);

    } 
});
}); 

</script>
```

This is from some tutorial I've found. And as I saw the `database.php` works. It prints right data, but in the `client.php` I can't get anything. What could be the problem?

---------EDITED---------

So, seems like on the web server runs php 4.4.7 and looks like json_encode() function does not wokrs because of that. I' ve found a "solution". I include upgrade.php, which implemets new methods for older versions of php, as far as i understands.
here is the webste of it http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/

I can't upgrade php version so could this be a good solution? At the moment it does not works

Comment: could you check the value of `data` inside the callback? what if you also define an `error` callback so you can check for errors?

Comment: try doing console.log(data); inside your success function

Comment: You should [drop `mysql_*` functions](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3656047#3656047).

Comment: Check in the browser console if you have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

First try to pring or alert your value.. if it is coming do according to your value u got..

```
 <div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced </div>

    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(function () 
    {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'database.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        

      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
       alert(data);  // check data value is coming or not..
        var name = data[0];              

         $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+name);

        } 
    });
    }); 

    </script>
```

check its printing value for you or not...

Comment: Your answer does not actually _answer_ the question :) Please post debug suggestions as comments and proper answers as answers.

Comment: Maybe i got the problem. It prints
Output:4.4.7

Comment: So php version could by too old. I' ve tested it on localhost(xampp), and worked fine, got this problem only in the webserver.But obviously xampp has som new version of php

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: '/database.php',      //Correct path.                 
  //data: "",                       
  type : 'Get',
  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(data)          
  {
     alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
     var name = data[0];    
     $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+name);
  } 
});
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(data); what value u r getting?

Comment: http:// localhost:49218/database.php what value u r getting?  http:// localhost:YourLocalHost/database.php . this page is inside any folder?

Comment: can u put her absolute url path of this database.php page?

Comment: no, database.php is on the same folder like client.php
I edited my post, don't you think, that my problem is because of the php version?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("database.php",function(data){
var entries = data;
$.each(entries,function(index,entry){
    //do stuff with json entry here
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Properly be so:

database.php

```
if (isset($_POST['getData'])) {
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM customers");
    $res=mysql_fetch_array($q);
    echo json_encode($res);
    die();
}
```

client.php

```
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced </div>

<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function () 
{
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'database.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
        type: "post",
        data: { getData: true },
        dataType: 'json',                //data format      
        success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
        {
            var name = data[0];              

            $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+name);

        } 
    });
}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in database.php

```
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM customers");

    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$a[]=$res['name'];
}
    echo json_encode($a);
```